# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" for url split

Tags: javascript

app.js

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(window.location);
//getting the access token from url 
var access_token = url.split("#")[1].split("=")[1].split("&")[0]; 
// get the userid 
var userId = url.split("#")[1].split("=")[2].split("&")[0]; 
console.log(access_token); 
console.log(userId);
```

the URL is something like this -
http://localhost:8080/?code=11111145676dfhr78899900876#*=*

Comment: can you post the entire url, cause the problem seems to be with the subsequent splits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this works:

```
...
var access_token = url.split("#")[1].split("=")[1].split("&")[0];
...
```

Problem was `url.split("#")[1].split("=")[2]`, which went error.
It should be `url.split("#")[1].split("=")[1]`.